# Firebase schedule data exports PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to set up a scheduled backup of my Firestore Database using cloud functions as documented in [this official guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export) but every time I'm  running the function, I get an error:

```
PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission
```

As described in the guide, I gave my default service account the "Admin Data Import Export" role by running this command:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding wag-prod \
    --member serviceAccount:wag-prod@appspot.gserviceaccount.com \
    --role roles/datastore.importExportAdmin
```

then adding the "Storage Admin" role to this account in the bucket permission by running this command:

```
gsutil iam ch serviceAccount:wag-prod@appspot.gserviceaccount.com:admin \
    gs://wag-prod-db-backup
```

Here is my cloud function:

```js
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
// contants
import { CF_LOCATION } from '../../constants/cf_config';
import { LoggingHelper } from '../../helpers/logging_helper';

const bucket = 'gs://wag-prod-db-backup';

const client = new admin.firestore.v1.FirestoreAdminClient({});

export default functions
  .region(CF_LOCATION)
  .pubsub.schedule('every day 00:00')
  .onRun(async () => {
    const projectId = process.env.GCP_PROJECT;
    try {
      const res = await client.exportDocuments({
        name: `projects/${projectId}/databases/(default)`,
        outputUriPrefix: bucket,
        // Leave collectionIds empty to export all collections
        // or set to a list of collection IDs to export,
        // collectionIds: ['users', 'posts']
        collectionIds: [],
      });
      LoggingHelper.logFunction(
        'scheduled:databaseBackup',
        {
          caller_id: 'none',
        },
        res,
      );
    } catch (error) {
      LoggingHelper.logFunctionError('internal', error.message, {
        caller_id: 'none',
      });
    }
  });
```

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Is the `projectId` getting the correct value? Looks like `process.env.GCP_PROJECT` is [not automatically available in new runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/env-var#newer_runtimes).

Comment: the sample code in the official Google documentation seems outdated...

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is a common error which may have various reasons-

1. As mentioned by Juan Lara there may not be the project id in the
   environment according to [this document](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/env-var#newer_runtimes) if you are using a
   runtime newer than Node JS 8.
2. The service account used by the Cloud Function does not have the
   necessary permission. But you have mentioned that you have given the
   permission using the command so it seems this is not the issue here.
   Still I will suggest you to re-verify them in the IAM section in the
   Google Cloud Console.
3. If you have initialized your Firestore Database in locked mode then
   all the read and write operations are blocked by default.

The rules will be like this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

I suggest you change this to the following and try :

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth !=null;
    }
  }
}
```